# Wordpress: Disable WP Object Caching DURING Runtime

Tags: wordpress, caching, memcached

I tried to disable WP Object Caching during Runtime using

`wp_using_ext_object_cache(false);`

Unfortunately it still does not update, e.g. user meta data, from the DB. So when I change a value directly in PHPMYAdmin, I would expect this to be read DIRECTLY out of the DB freshly.

Does `wp_using_ext_object_cache` not change/work during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found the solution after having searched hours and hours before actually posting.

```
# Disable WP Obj Caching ...
wp_using_ext_object_cache(false);
wp_cache_flush();
wp_cache_init();
```

Seems to really cleaning/resetting the WP_Object Object behind it -> So all subsequent calls will directly read from DB!